# SignalR application doesn't work on different computers/connections on the same URL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

So this is part of a bigger project, and I have posted a small test I created for the purpose of describing my problem. It work fine on one computer on multiple browsers (same or different browsers). But it does not work between different computers. I think perhaps I am misunderstanding how SignalR works and am making a stupid mistake, because I am stumped!

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Hub:

```
public class VBMDataHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        Clients.Others.broadcastConnected();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
var conn = $.connection.vBMDataHub;

//SIGNALR START
$.connection.hub.start();

conn.client.broadcastConnected = function () {
    console.log("ANOTHER USER HAS JUST CONNECTED");
};
```

Now all this does is, when someone has entered that page, it sends a console message to everyone else. So for example if I open my page in Chrome, and then open another tab and go to the same url, the first page will get that message. And if I refresh either one, the other one should get the message.

This works for multiple computers I've tried on each machine. But it does not update for other connections/computers.

I apologize if this is a really silly thing I overlooked while reading the tutorial. I feel like maybe I'm doing something completely wrong and misunderstanding how signalR works.

Comment: Have you tried doing `Clients.All` instead of `Clients.Others`?

Comment: Just tried! Unfortunately it seems to not make a difference.

Comment: are you testing with localhost?I mean do other computers connect to the same server? or each computer is running its own server?

Comment: I am testing after deploying to a shared dev server, so the computers are sharing the same server.

Comment: @JamesVerdune, were you able to figure it out? I am facing the same problem